# why does hibernate map tinyint(1) to a java.lang.Boolean?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums

Considering the following enum in Java:

```
public enum Color {
    RED,
    GREEN
}
```

The definition in the JPA Entity

```
@Column(name = "COLOR")
private Color color;
```

and the MySQL DDL:

```
`COLOR` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
```

Why does Hibernate 3.5 seem to always map the tinyint(1) to a java.lang.Boolean, leading to the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1351)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1251)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:264)
```

This seems to be fixed easily by changing the DDL to tinyint(2). However, I was wondering if this is intended and why hibernate maps to a Boolean, even though it should know that this should be mapped as an enum.

Comment: mysql used to not support 'bit' fields, and translated them to `tinyint(1)`. many interface libs were hardcoded to treat tinyint(1) as boolean to compensate.

Comment: Did you try columnDefinition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the mysql jdbc type mapping](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html), not only is this intended behaviour, it's documented. Strictly speaking, [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) isn't doing the mapping, the jdbc driver is. You could [file a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/) against mysql and make a case if you think this behaviour should be changed, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write a custom [UserType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) to tell hibernate to map the tinyint(1) to an enum

```
class EnumUserType<T extends Enum<T>> implements UserType { ... }
```

You just need to implement the `nullSafeSet` and `nullSafeGet` methods to map your enumeration to the integer from the result set.

Then add the Type annotation to your Entity column

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "com.myco.EnumUserType")
```

Of course you could tell mysql to NOT map the tinyint(1) to a bit by setting the [`tinyInt1isBit` JDBC connection property](http://arpan-khandelwal-tech.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/mysql-tinyint1isbit.html) to false, but this will affect all your tinyint(1)s.